# run script every last thursday of the month

Tags: cron, schedule

How to make a script run at e.g. 16:00 every last thursday of the month using gnome-schedule or cron?

Comment: 0 16 * * 4 test $(date +\%m) -ne $(date -d 7days +\%m) && export DISPLAY=:0 ;  scriptfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open crontab (`crontab -e`)and add this entry.

```
0 16 24-31 * 4 script_file
```

You can use [this](http://cron.nmonitoring.com/cron-generator.html) online cron generator.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Or use [this editor](http://www.corntab.com/pages/crontab-gui). It's a bit more comprehensive.

Comment: great, thanks. But it won't run on april 2014 :)

Comment: changing it to 24-31 will solve it :)

Comment: but then.. look at july 2014 :) Sorry, just kidding.. The question is solved. Thanks again.

Comment: :) glad that you solved the issue.

Comment: btw if the pc is off will this job work when I switch it on? Will anacron perform this task?

Comment: Cron doesn't run when the system is switched off. Anacron can perform this task where your system doesn't need to run like a server 24x7

Comment: In July 2014, wouldn't this run twice, on Thu 24th and Thu 31st?

Comment: From `man 8 crontab`: __The day of a command's execution can be specified  by  two  fields  —  day  of month, and day of week.  If both fields are restricted (i.e., aren't *), the command will be run when either field matches the current time.__ So won't this also be run every Thursday?

Comment: When last day of month is Wednesday February 28th I think this script breaks.

Comment: This is completely wrong. This will run on the 24th, 25th,...,31th **and** every Thursday. See the comment of @DanGravell or [IEEE Std 1003.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/crontab.html)

Comment: Warning: [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/#0_16_24-31_*_4) says that this will run "At 16:00 on every day-of-month from 24 through 31 AND on Thursday."
 (as others have already said)

Answer (score 2):

Faced with the same issue I created a script ([cron-last-sunday](http://xr09.github.io/cron-last-sunday/)) to help with this.

Here is a brief example of how easy you can achieve these "peculiar" requirements.

```
# every first saturday
30 6 * * 6 root run-if-today 1 && /root/myscript.sh

# every last sunday
30 6 * * 7 root run-if-today L && /root/myscript.sh

# every third tuesday
30 6 * * 2 root run-if-today 3 && /root/myscript.sh
```